# When is the matrix $(a,b,b,c)$ positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra

Not the most enlightening problem, but when is the following matrix positive definite?

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
b & c
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I know that by invoking [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion), we see that we need $a>0$ and $ac-b^2>0$. However, is it possible to go from something like

$$ax^2 + 2bxy + cy^2 >0 \text{ for all } x,y$$?

Comment: Sure. First suppose $y=0$, then you must have $a>0$. Now suppose $y\ne0$, then by rescaling we can take $y=1$; the quadratic in $x$ must have no roots, which implies $b^2-ac<0$.

Comment: @Rahul Ah thanks! Somehow I started with "$c > 0$" and then confused myself a little bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $x=1$, $y=0$ gives $a>0$, so that's necessary. Then
$$0<a(ax^2+2bxy+cy^2)=(ax+by)^2+(ac-b^2)y^2$$
so we also need $ac-b^2>0$. From this also, $a>0$ and $ac-b^2>0$
is sufficient.